# How to create users for mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create users and save them to my database. I have this login formula with css and html and the code to put it into my db:

```
function registerUser()
{

        echo "
        <form method='get' action=''>
        <div style=\"text-align: center;\"><input class=\"button\" style=\"z-index:1;\" type=\"submit\" name=\"reset\" value=\"Neues Spiel\">
        <a href=\"?site=highscore\" class=\"button\" style=\"z-index:1;\">Zur Highscore</a>
        </form>


        <form style=\"border:5; border-color:blue; \" align=\"center\" action=\"\" method=\"post\">
        <table style='background-color:#696969' border='5' align='center'>

        <tr>
            <th>Dein Username:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type=\"text\" size=\"24\" maxlength=\"50\"
            name=\"username\"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Dein Passwort:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type=\"password\" size=\"24\" maxlength=\"50\"
            name=\"password\"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Passwort Wiederholen:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type=\"password\" size=\"24\" maxlength=\"50\"
            name=\"password2\"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td><input style=\"margin-left:49;\" align=\"center\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Abschicken\" name=\"saveUser\"></tr></td>
        </table>
        </form>
        ";

}
```

and my `saveUser()` function:

```
function saveUser($username, $password, $passwordCheck)
{
    $this->db->exec("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ({$username}, {$password})");
}
```

And I got this in my other document to get access:

```
if(isset($_GET['saveUser'])){
        $user->saveUser($_GET['username'],$_GET['password'],$_GET['password2']);
    }
```

It does not work.

Comment: Not quite sure but I think you should write like {'$username'} instead of {$username}, same for password in your query.

Comment: Echoing what is basically only HTML is a bad idea, storing password in plaintext is a really bad idea and passing all this through a GET is probably the worst. I won't even mention possible duplicate users, password validation, etc ... That said, if you still wish to get help, you will have to provide more details on what you mean by "does not work"...

Comment: If your code to save the form data is in another document, you need to specify that document in the `action=` part of `<form method='get' action=''>`

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your script and check log/screen for potential errors.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will look over my code and fix my errors

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code and use this:

```
$this->db->exec("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('{$username}', '{$password}')");
```

And also one thing you forgot you need to validate your data to avoid sql injections, never ever trust an input coming from the user of any type.